WPF DataGrid disabling editing on validation errors
My view has a DataGrid that displays a ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>. To validate the input of MyViewModel properties, I use a ValidationRule that checks all model properties in the Validate method. Several MyViewModels are added to the DataGrid at once, which do not pass validation and require modification by the user. If user begin editing one row, DataGrid blocks the rest rows for editing (as far as I understand, while the edited DataGridRow.HasError == true). The thing is that the expected behavior of the user is that he will first fill in one property in all rows, then the other, etc. Pressing the Esc key while editing a row removes the validation errors of the row, and thus allows editing other rows, but the errors should be displayed if they are present. I wanted to try to force validation after clearing the errors and see what happens, but this error-clearing Esc pressing does not raise the DataGrid.KeyDown event.
Unfortunately, I can't change MyViewModel, and the numbers (and other data) from it are converted when the button is pressed. Of course, the button is enabled only when there are no ValidationErrors in any DataGridRow.
I want to know the answers to the following questions:

What happens inside the DataGrid (what events are fired) when I start editing a row, but there are still validation errors?
What exactly happens when I press the Esc key?
Is it possible to achieve a behavior so that validation errors are only displayed, but do not affect editing DataGrid?

A more or less suitable solution is to use DataGridTemplateColumns, in which the CellTemplate will be identical to the CellEditingTemplate, but I hope there is a more elegant solution.
Here is an example of repro:
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" 
          SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <validation:MyViewModelValidationRule ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue"
                                              ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
                  ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                <Ellipse Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                         StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Number"
                            Binding="{Binding FirstNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second Number" 
                            Binding="{Binding SecondNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tenth Number" 
                            Binding="{Binding TenthNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>

MyCollection is an ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>, and model looks like this:
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private string _firstNumber;
    public string FirstNumber 
    { 
        get => _firstNumber;
        set
        {
            _firstNumber = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstNumber)));
        }
    }
    ...
}

Validation rule looks like this:
public class MyViewModelValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        MyViewModel model = value switch
        {
            MyViewModel param      => param,
            BindingGroup group => (MyViewModel)group.Items[0]!,
            _                  => throw new NotSupportedException()
        };

        if (!uint.TryParse(model.FirstNumber, out _))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "First number is not a number");
        }
        else if (!uint.TryParse(model.SecondNumber, out _))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Second number is not a number");
        }
        ...
        else if (!uint.TryParse(model.TenthNumber, out _))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Tenth number is not a number");
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
}

